# MobX is updating the data in the input form coming from the web socket, but I need to make a change to this field

Tags: reactjs, mobx

When I receive data from the web socket, they are put into storage, and the component is wrapped in the observer function, and the received data is displayed in the input field, but when I try to make a change to this field, the value is updated and I cannot do anything, how can I can stop updating this data on onFocus of the input field

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from "react";
import {
    IconButton,
    Table,
    TableBody,
    TableCell,
    TablePagination,
    TableHead,
    TableRow,
    Tooltip,
    Button, TextField
} from "@mui/material";

import ExpandLess from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess";
import ExpandMore from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";
import Collapse from "@mui/material/Collapse";
import {Paper} from "@mui/material";
import {Context} from "../index";
import {observer} from "mobx-react-lite";


const headers = [{key: "id"}, {key: "title"}, {key: "address"}, {key: "value"}];

const App = observer(({taskTree, parent}) => {
    const {variables} = useContext(Context)
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({});
    const [parentTree, setParentTree] = useState()
    if (state["parentTasks"] === undefined) {
        const newstate = {...state, parentTasks: true};
        setState(newstate);
    }
    console.log(Object.values(parent).map(data => console.log(data)))
    //
    // const parentTree = parent.map(data => console.log(data))

    function TableTreeRow(taskTree, collapseId) {
        function getChildById(node, id) {
            let array = [];
            function getAllChild(nodes) {
                if (nodes === null) return [];
                array.push(nodes.id);
                if (Array.isArray(nodes.children)) {
                    nodes.children.forEach((node) => {
                        array = [...array, ...getAllChild(node)];
                        array = array.filter((v, i) => array.indexOf(v) === i);
                    });
                }
                return array;
            }

            //returns the node object that was selected
            function getNodeById(nodes, address) {
                if (nodes.id === address) {
                    return nodes;
                } else if (Array.isArray(nodes.children)) {
                    let result = null;
                    nodes.children.forEach((node) => {
                        if (!!getNodeById(node, address)) {
                            result = getNodeById(node, address);
                        }
                    });
                    return result;
                }

                return null;
            }

            return getAllChild(getNodeById(node, id));
        }

        const handleClick = item => {
            const tree = getChildById(taskTree, item)
            const parent = Object.keys(state)
            const matched = tree.filter( el => parent.indexOf( el ) > -1 );
            console.log(matched)
            const newstate = {...state, [item]: !state[item]};
            setState(newstate);
        };

        function findValue(id) {
            try {
                return (variables.variables[id].value)
            }
            catch(e){
                return "undefined"
            }
        }


        return taskTree.children.map(task => (
            <React.Fragment>
                <TableRow hover key={task.id} sx={{overflowWrap: 'anywhere'}}>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row" sx={{p: 0}}>
                        <Collapse
                            key={collapseId}
                            in={state[collapseId]}
                            unmountOnExit
                            sx={{p: 2,overflowWrap: 'anywhere'}}
                        >
                            {task.id}
                        </Collapse>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left" sx={{p: 0}}>
                        <Collapse
                            key={collapseId}
                            in={state[collapseId]}
                            unmountOnExit
                            sx={{p: 2,overflowWrap: 'anywhere'}}
                        >
                            {task.title}
                        </Collapse>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left" sx={{p: 0}}>
                        <Collapse
                            key={collapseId}
                            in={state[collapseId]}
                            unmountOnExit
                            sx={{p: 2,overflowWrap: 'anywhere'}}
                        >
                            {task.address}
                        </Collapse>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left" sx={{p: 0}}>
                        <Collapse
                            key={collapseId}
                            in={state[collapseId]}
                            unmountOnExit
                            sx={{p: 2,overflowWrap: 'anywhere'}}
                        >
                            <TextField
                                id="outlined-controlled"
                                label="Controlled"
                                value={findValue(task.id)}
                                
                            />
                        </Collapse>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell sx={{p: 0,}}>
                        <Collapse
                            key={collapseId}
                            in={state[collapseId]}
                            unmountOnExit
                            sx={{p: 2}}
                        >
                            {Array.isArray(task.children)
                                ? <Button
                                    key={task.id}
                                    onClick={() => handleClick(task.id)}
                                >
                                    {state[task.id] ? <ExpandLess/> : <ExpandMore/>}
                                </Button>
                                : null}
                        </Collapse>
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow >
                {Array.isArray(task.children) ? TableTreeRow(task, task.id) : null}
            </React.Fragment>
        ))
    }

    return (
        <Paper>
            <Table size="small">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        {headers.map(({key}) => (
                            <TableCell key={key}>
                                {key}
                            </TableCell>
                        ))}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                {Object.values(taskTree).map(data => {
                    if (Array.isArray(data.structure.children)) {
                        return (
                            <TableBody>
                                {TableTreeRow(data.structure, "parentTasks")}
                            </TableBody>
                        )
                    }
                })
                }
        </Table>
</Paper>
)
})

export default App
```

After I make a change in the input field, and on pressing the button (the functionality is not yet implemented), a post request should be sent to the server, which in turn will change this data. Data is taken from the OPC UA server and updated dynamically

The current implementation of the component does not give the desired effect, since I use MobX for the first time in a similar project